# How to use $ref with json-schema and top level properties

Tags: json, jsonschema, ajv

Hello friends :) I have a JSON Schema that looks like this:

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "Sync Repo Settings Config",
  "description": "Schema for defining the sync repo settings config",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "type": "object",
  "$ref": "#/definitions/repoConfig",
  "definitions": {
    "repoConfig": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "description": "A simple label for describing the ruleset.",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "selector": {
          "description": "For use in the org/.github repository. A GitHub repo search query that identifies the repositories which should be managed by the given rule.",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "squashMergeAllowed": {
          "description": "Whether or not squash-merging is enabled on this repository.",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "rebaseMergeAllowed": {
          "description": "Whether or not rebase-merging is enabled on this repository.",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "mergeCommitAllowed": {
          "description": "Whether or not PRs are merged with a merge commit on this repository.",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "deleteBranchOnMerge": {
          "description": "Either true to allow automatically deleting head branches when pull requests are merged, or false to prevent automatic deletion.",
          "type": "boolean"
        },
        "branchProtectionRules": {
          "description": "Branch protection rules",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "pattern": {
                "description": "Identifies the protection rule pattern.",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "dismissesStaleReviews": {
                "description": "Will new commits pushed to matching branches dismiss pull request review approvals.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "isAdminEnforced": {
                "description": "Can admins overwrite branch protection.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "requiredApprovingReviewCount": {
                "description": "Number of approving reviews required to update matching branches.",
                "type": "number"
              },
              "requiredStatusCheckContexts": {
                "description": "List of required status check contexts that must pass for commits to be accepted to matching branches.",
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              },
              "requiresCodeOwnerReviews": {
                "description": "Are reviews from code owners required to update matching branches.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "requiresCommitSignatures": {
                "description": "Are commits required to be signed.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "requiresStatusChecks": {
                "description": "Are status checks required to update matching branches.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "requiresStrictStatusChecks": {
                "description": "Are branches required to be up to date before merging.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "restrictsPushes": {
                "description": "Is pushing to matching branches restricted.",
                "type": "boolean"
              },
              "restrictsReviewDismissals": {
                "description": "Is dismissal of pull request reviews restricted.",
                "type": "boolean"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "permissionRules": {
          "description": "List of explicit permissions to add (additive only)",
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
              "team": {
                "description": "Team slug to provide access.",
                "type": "string"
              },
              "permission": {
                "description": "Permission to provide the team.  Can be one of (pull|push|admin)",
                "type": "string",
                "enum": ["pull", "push", "admin"]
              }
            },
            "required": ["team", "permission"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to create a re-usable `repoConfig` schema, which can also be represented in the root of my json documents.  I'm being fussy, and turning the `additionalProperties` setting off, just to make 100% everything is working as expected.  When I try to validate this document:

```json
{
   "rebaseMergeAllowed": false,
   "branchProtectionRules": [
      {
         "requiresCodeOwnerReviews": true,
         "requiredStatusCheckContexts": [
            "check1",
            "check2"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "permissionRules": [
      {
         "team": "team1",
         "permission": "push"
      }
   ]
}
```

I am getting the following error from the `ajv` npm module during validation:

```js
[
  {
    instancePath: '',
    schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
    keyword: 'additionalProperties',
    params: { additionalProperty: 'rebaseMergeAllowed' },
    message: 'must NOT have additional properties'
  }
]
```

If I take the collection of `properties` defined in my shared `repoConfig` object and directly inline them in the root of my schema document, the validator works as expected.

Comment: Care to mark an answer accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Ether's answer is correct, you actually have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.

(I think ajv actually allows `$ref` and `definitions` at the root level. The legality of this is debatable and unclear.)

Your problem here is in your use of `additionalProperties`, in that it cannot "see through" applicators, such as `$ref`.

> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
> values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
> and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6

In simpler terms, the `properties` and `patternProperties` **within the same schema object** as `additionalProperties` **only**.

If you need to continue using draft-07 of JSON Schema, then you need to redefine the `properties` at the same level (You can give them a value of `true`).

If you can move to a newer version of JSON Schema, you can use `unevaluatedProperties`, which in simple terms, CAN "see through" applicator keywords. It's a little more complex, but it would behave how you expect.

Answer (score 2):

In drafts 7 and earlier, you cannot use $ref in combination with any other keyword. To get around this, you can wrap the $ref inside an allOf:

```
"allOf": [ { "$ref": "#/definitions/repoConfig" } ],
... rest of your schema...
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Sadly, even after doing this, I get the same error.  I am starting to wonder if it's a bug in ajv.